# mouseover to a panel in flex

Tags: apache-flex, mouseover

I am new to flex.When i mouse over on the icon in the panel that particular panel should come front by overriding all other panel in the window.How can i do this Pleases help me out

Answer (score 1):

For bringing a panel to front, try this:
`

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[           
        protected function panel1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            setChildIndex(event.currentTarget as Panel, numChildren); 
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Panel width="200" height="400" y="50" x="50" rollOver="panel1_clickHandler(event)" title="back"/>
<mx:Panel width="200" height="400" id="otherPanel" rollOver="panel1_clickHandler(event)" title="front" />
```

`